# Is memcopying with an offset into a trivial copyable type allowed?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

I have two types:

```
struct A
{
   std::uint64_t lhs;
   std::uint64_t rhs;
   A(A const&) { ... };
};

struct B
{
    std::uint32_t a;
    std::uint16_t b;
    std::uint16_t c;
    std::uint8_t d[8];
};
```

I want to convert an object of type `A` to an object of type `B`. Strictly speaking `A` is **not** trivially copyable, because it has a user defined copy constructor. That means I cannot safely memcpy the entire object, like

```
std::memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(a));
```

because memcpy's behavior is unspecified for non trivially copyable types. Because of that, I want to copy `A::lhs` and `A::rhs` separately into `b`, but to do this I have to offset the pointer to `b`:

```
std::memcpy(&b, &a.lhs, sizeof(a.lhs));
std::memcpy(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&b) + sizeof(a.lhs), &a.rhs, sizeof(a.rhs));
```

Is this well defined behavior (assuming memcpying trivial copyable types is actually well defined behavior)?

Comment: Is moving `lhs` and `rhs` into it's own struct an option? That would make it trivially copyable and make all doubts go away.

Comment: @super you mean `A -> C -> B` where `C` is just a trivial version of `A` and do `A -> C` via assignment?

Comment: `+ sizeof(a.lhs)` ->  `+ offsetof(A, lhs)`. The code is invalid. No you can't do that. What is wrong with `b = rhs >> 16; c = rhs & 0xffff;` ? Is there any reason to use memcpy here?

Comment: `struct C { std::uint64_t lhs; std::uint64_t rhs };` and then `struct A : C { ... };` or `struct A { C c; ... };`

Comment: @KamilCuk I didn't know `offsetof` was a thing.

Comment: @super `A` is in an external API header, so your version isn't possible.

Comment: @KamilCuk yeah I canceled bit shifting out when I still had a single mempy. But now it might really be more viable. There is no reason for not using shifting

Comment: IMHO, the greater problem is the possible padding in `struct B`. On a language lawyer point of view, it is enough to say that copying into *more than one single element* of `struct B` is not defined per standard.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I hadn't alignment on my radar and `A` and `B` do have different alignment. So I guess mempcy is out of the game now.

Comment: The main problem with `memcpy` in your case would be endianness if you want your code to works as expected in either case (big or little endian). The alignment or padding might be a problem on some target and finally it is always risky to have undefined behavior (it might works on some compiler and with some options in a case like the above one).